# What is the most efficient way to toggle expand/contract split windows in vim?

Tags: vim

In tmux, there is a nice shortcut `ctrl+b z` to toggle expand/contract the current pane.

How do you achieve a similar effect in Vim?
You can `ctrl+w |` to maximize, `ctrl+w =` to make the windows the equal size, but this procedure takes two steps and also destroys the original sizes of the split windows if they were unequal in size.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZoomWin should do the trick,

[image: gif]

although it doesn't look like the latest version ([v25n](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ZOOMWIN)) is on [Github](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ZoomWin) yet.